# I've seen several catch blocks in some legacy code. Does that make any sense?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

While working on my current project, I've seen some strange code construction that looks like:

```
  async_api_call_with_throw_errors //pseudocode
    .then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
    .then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
    .then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
    .then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
    .catch((e) => {
        Sentry.captureException(e)
        if (e?.validateError) {
         //some actions
        } else {
          dispatch({ type: errorOccurred, errorText: e?.message, fatalError: false })
        }
      })
    .catch(e => {
      Sentry.captureException(e)
      dispatch({ type: errorOccurred, errorText: e, fatalError: false })
    })
```

If "catch" blocks catch several error types it is OK, but does two "catch" blocks with same error after "then" block make any sense?

I think not. But maybe I don't know something important about try...catch ?

Comment: Are you sure they were all part of the same try? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781818/multiple-catch-in-javascript

Comment: oh... you right in beginning is not any try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple catch can work if the preceding catch throws an error which is then caught by the succeeding catch.
Have a look at the below code.

```
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  throw 'Uh-oh!';
});

promise1.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  throw "Error was caught!"
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
})
// Expect Output:
//  > Uh-oh!
//  > Error was caught!
```

Hope this clears a few doubts.

Answer (score 2):

The catches are not for all the same try. The last catch is for the try block. But the first catch is for the promise chain.

```
try {
-------
.catch(e => {
  Sentry.captureException(e)
  dispatch({ type: errorOccurred, errorText: e, fatalError: false })
})
```

And the promise block is,

```
async_api_call_with_throw_errors //pseudocode
.then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
.then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
.then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
.then(() => async_call_with_throw_errors) //pseudocode
.catch((e) => {
    const eventId = Sentry.captureException(e)
    if (e?.validateError) {
     //some actions
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: errorOccurred, errorText: e?.message, fatalError: false })
    }
  })
```

Now, we should not use try/catch with async call like that. If you want to use try/catch block around async operation you should use await to call the async method and there should be no promise resolving chain. The code should be written as,

```
try {
  await async_api_call_with_throw_errors;
  await async_api_call_with_throw_errors;
  await async_api_call_with_throw_errors; 
    .....
} catch (error) {
   handle errors
}
```

By the way, you should make sure that the then function you want to use async/await should be an async function as well.

Comment: sorry about that but there is no "try" block at the beginning. My bad. I edit code :(

Answer (score 1):

It should work if the first catch throws an error, although I'm not sure why anyone would do it.